# how to read csv file and pass its values to a function parameters

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, csv, data-conversion

I have a csv file having one column and the values it contains like this:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GDdO.png)

and this function

```py
def yolo_to_coco(x_center, y_center, w, h,  image_w, image_h):
  w = w * image_w
  h = h * image_h
  x1 = ((2 * x_center * image_w) - w)/2
  y1 = ((2 * y_center * image_h) - h)/2
  return [x1, y1, w, h]``
```

when I pass value to this function
`image_w` and `image_h` I am passing from my own it is not in the csv

```py
test = yolo_to_coco(53.854, 2912.798, 398.71, 57.202,1024,1024)
```

the get the required result

```py
[-148993.02399999998, 2953417.7279999997, 408279.04, 58574.848]
```

I want to get each value from this file and pass to this function and the store in another csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dataframe.apply(function)` method. With this method you can apply this function to every row.
Let's create a dummy df.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'bbox': [[53.854, 2912.798, 398.71, 57.202],[31, 12,120, 20],[17, 72,170, 720]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

But you don't need to create dummy  df. You will read as

```
df = pd.read_csv ('/content/drive/MyDrive/bbox_file.csv')
```

let's create function. First argument will be row value. We will specify extra 2 arguments (image_w, image_h)

```
def yolo_to_coco(bbox,  image_w, image_h):
    row_list = list(bbox[1:-1].split(","))
    row_list = [float(i) for i in row_list]
    x_center, y_center, w, h = row_list
    w = w * image_w
    h = h * image_h
    x1 = ((2 * x_center * image_w) - w)/2
    y1 = ((2 * y_center * image_h) - h)/2
    return [x1, y1, w, h]
```

Now, We can apply this function to bbox column.You can pass any image_w,image_h values. It will create a pandas.series

```
df_coco_series = df["bbox"].apply(yolo_to_coco,image_w = 1024,image_h = 1024)
```

Finally converting to pandas.dataframe

```
df_coco = df_coco_series.to_frame()
print(df_coco)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, df_coco_series = df["bbox"].apply(yolo_to_coco,image_w = 1024,image_h = 1024) give an error 
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4) when i read and passed my csv file using pd.read_csv('')

Comment: But according to [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GDdO.png) you upload every row has 4 values to unpack. After reading your csv can you show me output of `print(df)` .

Comment: d = pd.read_csv ('/content/drive/MyDrive/bbox_file.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
   bbox
0      [1966.434, 1732.989, 74.433, 56.559]
1         [1996.24, 2137.9, 74.065, 65.971]
2        [1945.006, 1735.78, 73.305, 62.32]
3     [1272.286, 2415.643, 83.126, 202.482]
4                   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 710.51]
...                                     ...
1431   [881.355, 1364.876, 107.83, 108.787]
1432  [873.697, 1368.966, 123.584, 104.785]
1433        [5280.0, 219.175, 0.0, 254.037]
1434   [4311.567, 1777.49, 171.002, 285.78]
1435         [5280.0, 238.69, 0.0, 222.889]

Comment: @user181925 Bro i think you are new to pandas. don't do `d = pd.read_csv ('/content/drive/MyDrive/bbox_file.csv') df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`. In my answer i created dummy df just to show you. You will not create df same way i did. you will just read. So you will do `df = pd.read_csv ('/content/drive/MyDrive/bbox_file.csv')` . I will edit answer too.

Comment: You are right, I am new to it. After loading directly to df same result is coming.

Comment: @user181925 I got it .because it reads values as a string . We need to convert to a list of numbers. I edited function.